# Get Eureka instance Id

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I would like to know if it exist a way for an Eureka client to know it actual instanceId (I am looking for a solution that works both on same host and in distributed conf).

So far, I was using my manually defined `eureka.instance.instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${random.int}`, but each time I access it value, I get a new one due to the random. So it will always be different from the one that have been generated and gived to the server at registration time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the [RandomValuePropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/config/RandomValuePropertySource.html#RandomValuePropertySource--) is stateless, so you get new value everytime you access that property.

First, you might want to consider using the host:port as the instanceId, no randomness there.

If that's not good enough, Inject [EurekaInstanceConfigBean](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaInstanceConfigBean.java) and get the instanceId. (Requires some testing)

Best is to set the instance-id has a system property yourself before SpringApplication.run.

Comment: Is there a way to fetch the instance id that is already generated

Comment: you can use `eurekaInstanceConfigBean.getInstanceId()` to get the instance id.

Answer (score 4):

I have bit simple solution as i wanted to get the id that is being used instead from the property file.

```
    @Autowired
EurekaClient eurekaClient;

eurekaClient.getApplicationInfoManager().getInfo().getInstanceId();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be old, but I understand the frustration.

`ServiceInstance` would not be able to get the instance id since, it is an interface.

My solution here was

```
@Autowired
EurekaClient eurekaClient; 

....
eurekaClient.getInstancesById("id); // in which would return a List<InstanceInfo> 
//thus you would be able to access instanceId from InstanceInfo.
```

Hope this helps! Also, don't forget that EurekaClient should be configured on the scope of the module in question.

Cheers!